# Convert CollectionFS Database to files on Hard Drive

Tags: meteor, cdn

I have been creating a video uploader using meteor and have been using CollectionFS to store the files. Unfortunately under heavy load it takes extended amounts of time to load the videos to display, all of the video files are around 50MB. In order to fix the issue of strain on the collection I want to save all files currently in the CollectionFS collection to the drive so I can place them on a CDN.

I do not know how to save the files to the hard drive, so any enlightenment on the subject would be helpful. The strain on the server is forcing meteor to run out of memory a little too often.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact a mongodb question rather than meteor. Taken from the [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/), the following example shows you how to do this for one file. Of course, you can use find instead of findone and iterate over the result to write each individual file.

```
// returns GridFS bucket named "contracts"
GridFS myContracts = new GridFS(myDatabase, "contracts");

// retrieve GridFS object "smithco"
GridFSDBFile file = myContracts.findOne("smithco");

// saves the GridFS file to the file system
file.writeTo(new File("/tmp/smithco.pdf"));
```

There is also an official [mongofiles utility](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/) that you can use for the same purpose:

```
mongofiles -d records get smithco.pdf
```